# TypeError Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I developed a magento site on local server, and when everything was finished, i uploaded it on the server, and strange javascript errors popped up, and no jquery seems to work on the page. See below the screenshot of error console:

[image]

Here is the code which is causing the line 1072 error:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        if(!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)))){
            jQuery().UItoTop({
                text: "Top"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

and this is the code for line 133 error:

```
 jQuery('.ajax-fancybox').fancybox(
                {
                   hideOnContentClick : true,
                   width:600,
                   autoDimensions: true,
                   type : 'iframe',
                   showTitle: false,
                   scrolling: 'no',
                   afterLoad: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var frameBodyHeight = jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').height();
                            if(jQuery(window).height() > frameBodyHeight+30){
                                jQuery('.fancybox-inner').css('height', frameBodyHeight);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            );
```

The first error of prototype.js was appearing on localhost as well, but that didin't cause any problem. I don't know why this error was appearing, while i didn't touch the prototype.js file.

Here is the link of the site: http://bit.ly/RfAQNX

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd say explore the code with some breakpoints and chrome dev tools

Comment: I don't know how to use breakpoints and chrome dev tools.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPXeWjWp-8Y

Comment: I'll watch the video. Meanwhile if possible please have a look at the site, you may be able to find out the issue.

Comment: This is just a guess, but watching your site load I notice quite a few .js files are loading before jquery.min.js -- so maybe it is loading the jquery extensions you are using too early, and they are not getting set up correctly.  That might be solved by loading jquery earlier in the list of scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul. I re-checked only Magento default Prototype and scriptaculous files got loaded before jquery file. And these are not dependent on jquery, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Here's the problem: you're not using Angular Fullstack

Comment: `Angular Fullstack ` What is that? I haven't heard the name before.

Comment: is it fancybox,UItoTop is a third party plugin? I did not see you load the plugin

Comment: @Se0ng11 You identified the issue correctly. Please post it as an answer, i'll mark it as correct. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it fancybox,UItoTop is a third party plugin? I did not see you load the plugin, try to load the plugin as needed